# How to determine the focal length of a combination of two convex lenses separated by a distance $d$ experimentally without formula?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, lenses, experimental-technique

I have done this experiment to find out the equivalent focal length of a combination of 2 convex lenses of slightly different focal length and have applied the formula for the equivalent focal length separated by a distance $d$.

But I am not able to understand how to verify it. 
Is there any other way we can determine the same using $u$,  $v$,  distance between the lenses or something? 
I have been asked to find it out  'experimentally' without using formula and then tally it with the answers I have got using the formula.

Comment: I don't think it's true in general that the combination of two thin lenses acts like a thin lens. It may be true as an approximation when the lenses are close compared to their focal length.

Answer (score 1):

Forget—for a moment—that the system under discussion is two lens. Just focus on the question

> How do I make an experimental measurement of the focal length of [an optical element]?

For instance, how would you measure the focal length of a single convex lens? (The problem is considerably harder if the optical element is diverging, BTW, so let's focus on the converging part of the problem to start.)

Now, this is a very basic problem and there is a well known answer: you measure the image distance when projecting a very distant object. That is, you hold the lens up near a screen and move it around until you get a crisp image of the landscape seen through the laboratory window, and the distance from the lens to the screen *is* is the focal length. (You may want to darken the room before starting.)

To see why this works look at the thin lens formula:<sup>1</sup>
$$ \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{d_o} + \frac{1}{d_i} \;, \tag{1}$$
and notice that is $d_o \gg f$ and $d_o \gg d_i$ then the fraction $1/d_o$ is much smaller than either of the other fractions and we can simplify (1) to
$$ \frac{1}{f} \approx \frac{1}{d_i} $$
or even 
$$ f \approx d_i \;.$$.

Finally, we need to pay attention to the fact that our optical element is a compound system and probably isn't "thin". As it turns out the only adjustment we need to make is defining<sup>2</sup>

- **object distance** as the distance from the subject to the leading element of the compound system.
- **image distance** as the distance from the trailing element of the compound system to the image.

---

If your two-element system is diverging, then the measurement requires you to combine it with a third element that is converging. But the pattern "figuring out how to do the measurement *without* worrying too much about the nature of the system being measured" remains the same.

---

<sup>1</sup> With a two (or more) element system the word "thin" probably doesn't apply anymore, but we can fudge it by choosing the right definitions for object distance and image distance.

<sup>2</sup> Question for the student: how do the rules for treating multi-element systems imply that these are the natural definitions of $d_o$ and $d_i$?